# Weird behaviour of GORMs callback

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am aiming to track all queries againt the database (MySQL), done by my application (Go).

This is the init function, where I register a global call back after a query has been performed:

```
func InitDatabase() error {
    err = DBEnv.Db.Callback().Query().After("*").Register("full_logger", setQueryLogger)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

// Querylogger
func setQueryLogger(db *gorm.DB) {
    sql, vars := db.Statement.SQL.String(), db.Statement.Vars
    rows := db.Statement.RowsAffected
    varsJson, err := json.Marshal(vars)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.Exec("INSERT INTO `query_logs` (`sql`,`parameters`, `rows_affected`, `executed_at`, `executed_by`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", sql, varsJson, rows, time.Now(), 1)
}
```

This is my user struct

```
type User struct {
    ID                    uint64         `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt             time.Time      `json:"createdAt"`
    CreatedBy             uint64         `json:"createdBy" validate:"required,gt=0"`
    UpdatedAt             time.Time      `json:"updatedAt"`
    UpdatedBy             uint64         `json:"updatedBy" validate:"required,gt=0"`
    DeletedAt             gorm.DeletedAt `json:"deletedAt"`
    DeletedBy             sql.NullInt64  `json:"deletedBy" validate:"required_with=DeletedAt"`
    ImportedBy            sql.NullInt64  `json:"importedBy" validate:"required_with=ImportedAt"`
    ImportedAt            sql.NullTime   `json:"importedAt" validate:"required_with=ImportedBy"`
    Email                 string         `json:"email" validate:"required"`
    Password              string         `json:"password" validate:"required"`
    FirstName             string         `json:"firstName" validate:"required"`
    LastName              string         `json:"lastName" validate:"required"`
    Active                bool           `json:"active" validate:"required"`
    LastPasswordChangedAt time.Time      `json:"lastPasswordChangedAt" validate:"required"`
    ActivatedBy           sql.NullInt64  `json:"activatedBy" validate:"required_with=ActivatedAt,gt=0"`
    ActivatedAt           sql.NullTime   `json:"activatedAt" validate:"required_with=ActivatedBy"`
    DeactivatedBy         sql.NullInt64  `json:"deactivatedBy" validate:"required_with=DeactivatedAt,gt=0"`
    DeactivatedAt         sql.NullTime   `json:"deactivatedAt" validate:"required_with=DeactivatedBy"`
    RoleId                uint64         `json:"roleId" validate:"required,gt=0"`
    InstituteId           sql.NullInt64  `json:"instituteId"`
}
```

This the method for searching:

```
func (u *User) FindFirst() *User {
    db.DBEnv.Db.First(u)
    return u
}
```

And this is the call:

```
user3 := (*user.User).FindFirst(&user.User{ID: 3})
```

GORM makes the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = ? ORDER BY `users`.`id`  LIMIT 1
```

And in the query logger it makes:

```
INSERT INTO `query_logs` (`sql`,`parameters`, `rows_affected`, `executed_at`, `executed_by`) VALUES (3, 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = ? ORDER BY `users`.`id` LIMIT 1', '[3]', 1, '2024-01-29 19:46:35.978')
```

Why is GORM injecting the searched ID as an additional parameter into the db.Exec funtion? This causes the following error

```
sql: expected 5 arguments, got 6
```

Do I miss something out, or is this a bug?

-- Edit
I was asked for the querylog table structure:

```
create table query_logs(
    id bigint unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
    `sql` text not null,
    `parameters` json null,
    rows_affected bigint unsigned not null default 0,
    executed_at datetime        not null default current_timestamp,
    executed_by bigint unsigned not null,
    foreign key (executed_by) references users (id) on delete restrict on update restrict
) ENGINE = Innodb;
```

Comment: I have no idea, but... can you double check these things?: For example, you're not really checking the result of `db.Exec` in the code your posted. Can you debug and really make sure the error is where you think it is?

Comment: Could you show the `query_logs` table structure?

Comment: yes:
create table query_logs(
    id bigint unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
    `sql` text not null,
    `parameters` json null,
    rows_affected bigint unsigned not null default 0,
    executed_at datetime        not null default current_timestamp,
    executed_by bigint unsigned not null,
    foreign key (executed_by) references users (id) on delete restrict on update restrict
) ENGINE = Innodb;

Comment: I tried with PostgreSQL and end up with `mismatched param and argument count`. As I suspected GORM can't deal with recursive queries here because executing a raw query inside `setQueryLogger` leads to trying to log this raw query itself using this method. If you try to create another connection to the same or different DB with `query_logs` table and use it to execute this raw query it will work just fine

Comment: You mean .Raw is handeled like a Select statement in GORm? Its a good point, I will try tomorrow to write the log entry with another wrapper or sqlraw.

Answer (score 0):

```
func setQueryLogger(db *gorm.DB) {
    // Check if we're already logging to avoid recursive call
    if _, ok := db.InstanceGet("logging"); ok {
        return // If we're already logging, return immediately to avoid recursion
    }

    sql, vars := db.Statement.SQL.String(), db.Statement.Vars
    rows := db.Statement.RowsAffected
    varsJson, err := json.Marshal(vars)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Set a flag to indicate that we're currently logging to prevent recursive logging
    db.InstanceSet("logging", true)

    db.Exec("INSERT INTO `query_logs` (`sql`,`parameters`, `rows_affected`, `executed_at`, `executed_by`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", sql, varsJson, rows, time.Now(), 1)
}
```

If the problem is with recursive calls, you should be able to solve it by implementing it like this

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately it didn't help. Even if I dodn't know what the root cause of the problem is, I could fix it when I am using a global DB-handler. Instead of 
`db.Exec("INSERT ...` I use `DBEnv.Db.Exec("INSERT ...`